# Local variable alignment for ATI/AMD OpenCL

Tags: opencl, gpu, memory-alignment, ati, amd-processor

I've been having trouble with a misaligned structure.  Here are the structures involved:

```
struct Ray
{
    float4 origin;
    float4 dir;
    float len;
    float dummy [3];
};

struct RayStack
{
    struct Ray r [STACK_DEPTH];
    int depth [STACK_DEPTH];
    float refr [STACK_DEPTH];
    int top;
    float dummy [3];
};
```

Incidentally, STACK_DEPTH is a multiple of 4.  I've been careful to make sure that all the structures are a multiple of 16 in size and that float4's within are on an aligned boundary.

The problem is when I use it as a local variable, the structure RayStack is unaligned:

```
struct RayStack stack;
printf("stack: %p\n", &stack);
```

The stack address ends up ending in 8 and not 0 as I would want for a 16-byte aligned structure.  This causes a crash on ATI cards (although Intel and nVidia are not bothered by it).  I've tried placing __attribute__((aligned(16))) in the structure (before and after), and in the local variable definition and that doesn't change anything.  Actually, adding a printf statement fixed the problem although I have no idea how.

Is there away to ensure that the local variable stack is aligned on a 16 byte boundary and stop the crashing on ATI cards.

Thanks!

Comment: UPDATE: I just discovered the problem went away on the 12.8 drivers.  I think the 12.10 drivers broke something in the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You do know that **arrays** in structures have to be aligned to a 16 byte boundary?
What's the "dummy" array for? Padding? If so, don't use arrays for padding.
From my experience with Nvidia, ATI and Intel, the following is the most safe method:

```
struct Ray
{
    float4 origin;
    float4 dir;
    float len;
    float padding1;
    float padding2;
    float padding3;
};

struct RayStack
{
    struct Ray r[STACK_DEPTH];
    int depth[STACK_DEPTH];
    float refr[STACK_DEPTH];
    int top;
    float padding1;
    float padding2;
    float padding3;
};
```